# Angular js ui tree throwing exception - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

Getting exception in console when my page loads for tree.
Also there is a heavy performance issue which makes at least 30 seconds to tree to load.

#### Html page

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="items_renderer.html">
        <div ui-tree-handle>
            <span ng-bind-html="item.name| highlight:pattern | trust"></span>
        </div>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="item.items">
            <li ng-repeat="item in item.childCategoryList" ui-tree-node
                ng-include="'items_renderer.html'"
                ng-click="pc.att(item.categoryId)"
                ng-hide="!treeFilter(item,pattern,supportedFields) && !dim"
                ng-class="{'filtered-out':!pc.treeFilter(item,pattern,supportedFields) && dim}">
            </li>
        </ol>
    </script>
    <div ui-tree>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="item.items">
            <li ng-repeat="item in pc.catList" ui-tree-node
                ng-include="'items_renderer.html'"
                ng-hide="!treeFilter(item,pattern,supportedFields) && !dim"
                ng-class="{'filtered-out':!pc.treeFilter(item, pattern,supportedFields) && dim}">
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### controller.js

```
vm.catAttList = response.data.data.catAttList;
```

#### Console

```
angular.js:12783 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Scope.e.init (localhost:8080/web/app/bower_components/angular-ui-tree-master/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.js:6:1243)
```

Comment: <li ng-repeat="item in item.childCategoryList" ui-tree-node="" ng-include="'items_renderer.html'" ng-click="pc.att(item.categoryId)" ng-hide="!treeFilter(item,pattern,supportedFields) &amp;&amp; !dim" ng-class="{'filtered-out':!pc.treeFilter(item,pattern,supportedFields) &amp;&amp; dim}" class="ng-scope angular-ui-tree-node"> ---- This error is also showing in console

Comment: I can't see `vm.catAttList` anywhere in your template.

Comment: @micronyks - Its actually declared in the controller. I am calling it in html by referring controller name.

Comment: where it is? still I can't see it.

Comment: @micronyks - I havent post the controller code. It is like this - var vm = null; vm.catAttList = response.data.data.catAttList; Getting the list as a response

Comment: as `catAttList` contains data, it should be used in HTML but in your case you don't use it.

Comment: @micronyks - my requirement here is for ui tree.